The limit of a sequence defined on a function with two variables.
$$f(s,x)=\dfrac{2+3s\sqrt[3]{x}}{(1+s\sqrt[3]{x})(1+x)}$$
Let $s_0=0.01$, $s_{k+1}=\displaystyle\int_0^{s_k}f(s_k,x)\ \mathrm{d}x$.
Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} s_k$ exists.
I can understand that $f$ behaves like $2$ near $0$ and behaves like $3\ln{x}$ when $x$ is large enough.
I want to use Monotone Convergence Theorem, which needs to prove that $\{s_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is monotone and bounded.
However, I can't prove that the dividing point of $f(s,x)-s$ being increasing, by $f$ acting like $2$, and being decreasing, by $f$ acting like $3\ln{x}$, is just the only fixed point $s^\ast$ with $s^\ast=\displaystyle\int_0^{s^\ast} f(s^\ast,x)\ \mathrm{d}x$.

Note
$$ s_1=0.0199167>0.01=s_0,s_2=0.0395213>s_1 $$
and hence one can conjecture that $\{s_k\}$ is increasing. Also note
$$\frac{\partial f(s,x)}{\partial s}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{(1+s\sqrt[3]{x})^2(1+x)}>0.$$
Suppose $s_k\ge s_{k-1}$. Then
$$ s_{k+1}-s_k=\int_0^{s_k}f(s_k,x)dx-\int_0^{s_{k-1}}f(s_{k-1},x)dx=\int_{s_{k-1}}^{s_k}f(s_k,x)dx+\int_0^{s_{k-1}}[f(s_k,x)-f(s_{k-1},x)]dx\ge0 $$
and hence $s_{k+1}\ge s_k$. By induction, $\{s_k\}$ is increasing.

Thank u very much. I got it!
